# Как в Joomla модуле получить домен сайта?

Tags: php, joomla

В модуле вывожу простой код с картинкой, и хочу получить путь к шаблону, когда пишу так

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$template_url = $this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template;
?>
<img src="<? echo $logo; ?>/images/blocks_services_im1.png"/>
```

То выдает ошибку **Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in** 
Как получить этот путь? Прошу Вашей помощи.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем за помощь, нашел решение сам, может пригодится кому.

```
defined( '_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$template = $app->getTemplate();
$template_url = JURI::root(true).'/templates/'.$template.'/';

<img src="<? echo $template_url; ?>/images/blocks_services_im1.png"/>
```